# How to get eigenvalue of 4 by 4 matrix out of each 2 by 2 matrices in quarters?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quartics

I have a very complicated 4 by 4 matrices with lots of complex variables in each entry. I can divide the matrix into quarters such as

M = $\begin{pmatrix}
M_1 & M_2 \\ M_2^\dagger & M_3
\end{pmatrix}
$

where $M_1,M_2,M_3$ are all 2 by 2 hermitian matrices with known eigenvalues. 
Given this knowledge, How can I get the eigenvalues of matrix M?

(I tried it in Mathematica but it only returns 'Root[...]' with very complicated and lengthy arguments.)

Each matrix is given as

$M_1=$
\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
4 \phi ^2 |h_d|^2 |\lambda _{\mu }|^2+|\lambda_{\mu}|^2\phi ^4 +3|\lambda_{\nu}|^2|l|^4 -2m_{\text{LHu}}^2 & 6 A_{\nu }^* \lambda_{\nu}^*{l^*}^2 +6 \lambda _{\mu } \lambda_{\nu}^*\phi ^2 l^* h_d +18 |\lambda_{\nu}|^2 l^3 l^* \\
6 A_{\nu}\lambda_{\nu}l^2 +6 \lambda _{\nu}\lambda _{\mu }^*\phi^2lh_d^*+18 |\lambda_{\nu}|^2|l|^2 {l^*}^2 & 4 \phi ^2|\lambda_{\mu}|^2 |h_d|^2 +|\lambda_{\mu}|^2\phi^4 +3|\lambda_{\nu}|^2|l|^4 -2m_{\text{LHu}}^2\\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
M_2=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
4 l \phi ^2 h_d |\lambda_{\mu}|^2 & 4 |\lambda _{\mu}|^2\phi ^2 l h_d^* +3 \lambda _{\mu}\lambda_{\nu}^*\phi^2 \left(l^*\right)^2 \\
4 |\lambda _{\mu}|^2\phi ^2 l^* h_d + 3\lambda_{\mu}\lambda_{\nu}^* \phi ^2 l^2  & 4|\lambda_{\mu}|^2 \phi ^2 l^*h_d^* \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
M_3=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
-2 g^2 |h_d|^2 +|\lambda_{\mu}|^2\phi ^4 + m_{\text{Hd}}^2 & -g^2 {h_d^*}^2 \\
-g^2 h_d^2 & -2 g^2 |h_d|^2 +|\lambda_{\mu}|^2\phi ^4 + m_{\text{Hd}}^2  \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: Are you looking for a general formula, or do you have specific matrices in mind?  If the latter, please post them.

Comment: I wonder if there is a general formula, however, in case it's not available I will post it soon.

Comment: It's a quartic equation whose coefficients are sums of principal minors. In theory there is an explicit formula for the roots, but it would be super lengthy.